# emberjs ember-data and jasmine testing

Tags: javascript, ember.js, jasmine, ember-data

I am trying to test a DS.Model using jasmine.   I am trying to test that when i create a record it is setup properly.

When i do

```
bb = App.BuildingBlock.createRecord(name: "Test")
```

i get the error

> Cannot read property 'createRecord' of undefined

but if i do

```
bb = App.BuildingBlock.create(name: "Test")
```

i get

> Error: You should not call `create` on a model. Instead, call `createRecord` with the attributes you would like to set.

So it seems to know its a model ???     Also if i do

```
expect(App.BuildingBlock).toBeDefined()
```

it passes.

Anyone help me with this ?

thanks
Rick

Comment: weird, can you post more context ? createRecord() require a hash {name: 'test'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the top of your spec

```
store = DS.Store.create({ revision: 4 })
```

Then use

```
store.createRecord(App.BuildingBlock, {name: "Test"});
```

The reason for the errors you're seeing is that DS.Model aliases createRecord to the store and that is what is undefined.

At the bottom of [model.js](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/model.js) you will see the following lines:

```
DS.Model.reopenClass({
  isLoaded: storeAlias('recordIsLoaded'),
  find: storeAlias('find'),
  filter: storeAlias('filter'),

  _create: DS.Model.create,

  create: function() {
    throw new Ember.Error("You should not call `create` on a model. Instead, call `createRecord` with the attributes you would like to set.");
  },

  createRecord: storeAlias('createRecord')
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot i thought i was including the file in my app that is setting up the store but was not!    Also this way is probably better for unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try creating a JsFiddle of your problem?  I don't see any problem with your first call to create the DS Model.  You can't call .create() on a DS Model so that makes sense and your DS Model seems to exist.    Are these tests being run with two different setups where the call to createRecord App or BuildingBlock don't exist?  Are you sure your store is defined on your App (App.store) and that there is something wrong there?